# Positioning UL LI select box

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need your help. What I am trying to accomplish is to use CSS to style my custom UL LI element like a real list box. I would like to get the 2 elements to merged with each other as well as to prevent the UL from shifting down other HTML elements under it. Below is problem that I am facing:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umvpa0a0/1/

[image]

Here is a picture of the desired result:

[image]

Here is the HTML & CSS in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#recent {
    width: 175px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.search_field {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 175px;
    position: relative;
}

.search_field input {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#btn_arrow {
    border: none;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.test {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="search_field">
<input id="fileno" type="text">
<input type="button" value="&#9660;" id="btn_arrow">
</div>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search">
<ul id="recent"><li>3434</li></ul>
<div class="test"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.everything {
    position: relative;
}
#recent {
 width: 175px;
 border: 1px solid red;
    border-top: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
}
.search_field {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 175px;
    position: relative;
}

.search_field input {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#btn_arrow {
    border: none;
    width: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.test {
 width: 100%;
 background: blue;
 height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="everything">
<div class="search_field">
<input id="fileno" type="text">
<input type="button" value="&#9660;" id="btn_arrow">
</div>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search">
<ul id="recent"><li>3434</li></ul>
<div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Just put everything inside a new div styled with the `position: relative` property, add the `position: absolute` and the `top: $px` properties to #recent and set a background to it (white).